# Symfony inner Join with doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to translate follow query using doctrine methods

```
    select * from scheda s join statoscheda ss on ss.id = s.idStatoScheda
```

i've tried this but doesn't work:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em
        ->getRepository('SchedaBundle:Scheda')
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->join('s.StatoScheda', 'ss')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: What do you get as result and what do you expect instead? The query looks fine to me..

Comment: Also, what's result of `getQuery` and how does Scheda entity look like?

Comment: This query generate an error:
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 81 near 'ss WHERE ss.id': Error: Class MyProject\SchedaBundle\Entity\Scheda has no association named StatoScheda

I expect many row results.